# How to use Mongoose data on the client site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDB User model that looks like this:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,

  user_id: Number,

  github: String,
  tokens: Array,

  profile: {
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    gender: { type: String, default: '' },
    age: { type: String, default: '' },
    location: { type: String, default: '' },
    website: { type: String, default: '' },
    picture: { type: String, default: '' },
  }
}, { timestamps: true });

/**
 * Password hash middleware.
 */
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) { return next(); }
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

/**
 * Helper method for validating user's password.
 */
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
    cb(err, isMatch);
  });
};

/**
 * Helper method for getting user's gravatar.
 */
userSchema.methods.gravatar = function (size) {
  if (!size) {
    size = 200;
  }
  if (!this.email) {
    return `https://gravatar.com/avatar/?s=${size}&d=retro`;
  }
  const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(this.email).digest('hex');
  return `https://gravatar.com/avatar/${md5}?s=${size}&d=retro`;
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

And I wanna use the data that it generates on the client side, like shown in this example on the server side:

```
 var User = require('../models/User.js');

 exports.getUsers = (req, res) => {
   User.find((err, docs) => {
      res.render('allusers/users', { users: docs });
   });
 };
```

But I can't do `require` on the client side... So how could I use the data on the client side?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I can't understand why you want to "require" the mongoose on the client side. in the line `res.render('allusers/users', { users: docs });` docs is a json like any other json. You can do everything you want on the client side with the docs json.

Comment: @danilodeveloper But how would I get access to the docs from the client side, when docs is defined on the server side?

Comment: Are you using some engine (jade, ejs)?

Comment: Yes @LucasCosta I'm using jade :)